# captured image quality is low in gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am creating an android app in which the user can click the images which would be shown in grid view once the image is captured this part works fine but the quality of the image is very low and even if i take the image from the high resolution camera it shows the width and height of the image as 160 and 200 px respectively.
 I would like to know is there any way to capture the image in original size than compress the image what we do in whatsapp. since i am a newbie to android i don't know what i have to do.

```
public class CamAct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button captureBtn = null;
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
private Uri picUri;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
private GridView grid;
private  List<String> listOfImagesPath;

public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GridViewDemo/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camlayout);

    captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn1);
    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);

    listOfImagesPath = null;
    listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
    if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {    
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.capture_btn1) {
         try {  
            Intent captureIntent = new      Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
            imageDirectory.mkdirs();
            String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listOfImagesPath = null;
            listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
            if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
                grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
            }
        }
    }
}

private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
    List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
    if (f.exists()) {
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);

        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            File file = files[i];
            if(file.isDirectory())
                continue;
            tFileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
    }
    return tFileList;
}
```

ImageAdapter:

```
 public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> imgPic;
    public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
    {
        context = c;
        imgPic = thePic;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        if(imgPic != null)
            return imgPic.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[16 * 1024];
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

            if(fs!=null) {
                bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                imageView.setId(position);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 160));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(fs!=null) {
                try {
                    fs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");`. You take the thumbnail instead of the original picture. You are number ### who happens this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(subname.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Snackbar.make(view, "Select Subject", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                ImagefileUri = Uri.fromFile(getFile());

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, ImagefileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST){
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int dw = size.x;
            int dh = size.y;
            // Load up the image's dimensions not the image itself
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagefileUri.getPath(),
                    bmpFactoryOptions);
            int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight
                    / (float) dh);
            int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth
                    / (float) dw);
            Log.v("HEIGHTRATIO", "" + heightRatio);
            Log.v("WIDTHRATIO", "" + widthRatio);
            if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) {
                if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                    // Height ratio is larger, scale according to it
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                } else {
                    // Width ratio is larger, scale according to it
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                }
            }
            // Decode it for real
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagefileUri.getPath(),
                    bmpFactoryOptions);
            InitilizeGridLayout();

            // loading all image paths from SD card
            imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();

            // Gridview adapter
            adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(Cam.this, imagePaths,
                    columnWidth);

            // setting grid view adapter
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // user cancelled Image capture
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // failed to capture image
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

It will capture the image as per the camera width and height so you will get the image in good quality as well as the image adapter you are using has an temp storage which can store only 5 or 6 images of high quality so change the grid view .To know more about displaying images from sdcard to gridview use the following link: [Loading images from sdcard and display it in gridview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Hope this code helps you:)